# How do I set file permission to MODE_WORLD_READABLE

Tags: android, media-player

I am downloading an audio file to my Android application's cache that must then be accessed with MediaPlayer.  The file gets created with permissions of -rw------- (as seen in Eclipse's File Explorer).

With these permissions, the MediaPlayer cannot access the audio file.  Failure is shown in logcat as:

```
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

My app targets API level 8.

How do I set the downloaded audio file's permissions to make it readable by the MediaPlayer?

By the way, I am creating the file with:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fRecording);
```

When I try to create the file as MODE_WORLD_READABLE, no file is created:

```
FileOutputStream out = activity.openFileOutput(fRecording.getAbsolutePath(), Activity.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

The logcat error using openFileOutput is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /data/data/com.calltrunk.android/cache/727adda7-0ef1-490f-9853-fe13ad1e9416 contains a path separator
```

Comment: When I change the line to "FileOutputStream out = activity.openFileOutput(fRecording, Activity.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);" I am seeing an error message in Eclipse of "The method openFileOutput(String, int) in the type ContextWrapper is not applicable for the arguments (File, int)"

Comment: It should be, FileOutputStream out = activity.openFileOutput("<Audio File Name>", Activity.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

Comment: The file is created with the correct permissions, but it seems to be moved "automatically" from cache to files within my application.  I will start a new question.

Comment: @user370305 - I managed to delete your crucial comment:  I should be accessing the file as "/data/data/<package_name>/files/<Audio_File_Name>".  I believe that will do the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Call `openFileOutput()` with the name of the file and the operating
  mode. This returns a `FileOutputStream` with permission
  `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`.
- Write to the file with `write()`.
- Close the stream with `close()`.

**For example:** (Code for txt file, in your case its a Audio file make changes according to it)

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Comment: If you want to pass the file on you need the filename as well. Which you get with `getFileStreamPath(FILENAME);`

Answer (score 4):

Starting with API 9 `File` object has [`setReadable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setReadable(boolean,%20boolean)) method (also `setWritable` and `setExecutable`). It's two args version can be used to set the read permission for all users as well (i.e. it becomes `-rw-r--r--` in your case):

```
File file = new File("path_to_your_file");
file.setReadable(true, false);
```